# Delphi: Creating a TComboBox in a dynamically created form at runtime

Tags: forms, delphi, dynamic, macros, scripting

Okay, I am working in a project that was originally done in D7.  And I am doing double duty here as I am working on fixing bugs in the original code and attempting to port it over to XE3/4.  Kinda hard when the original author used some none-open source kits for the project.

But anyways, the app is a scripting/macroing program.  As part of the custome scripting/macroing language. There is a ability to create very simple basic forms for user input.  The forms are created dynamically at runtime based on the script/macro the script/macro author has created.  I have already fixed some bugs in the code for the creation of the forms.  But, there is one that I just can not figure out.

When creating a TComboBox for the parent form and setting the Text property AT component creation.  The text in the Text property is not displayed.

**Here is the code to create the form:**

```
procedure CreateForm(var wFrm: TForm; sName: String);
var
  iLoop, iPos, iLen: Integer;
  iFormHeight, iFormWidth: Integer;
  lh, hresult1, hresult2: Integer;
  sWork, sWork2, sLine, CmdName: String;
  lstForm, lst: TStringList;
  pnl: TPanel;

begin
  iFormHeight := 80;
  iFormWidth := 400;
  hresult1 := 0;
  lst := TStringList.Create;

  iLoop := lstForms.IndexOf(Trim(UpperCase(sName)));
  if iLoop < 0 then
  begin
    AbortError('Form "' + sName + '" could not be found!');
    Exit;
  end;

  lstForm := TStringList(lstForms.Objects[iLoop]);

  for iLoop := 0 to lstForm.Count - 1 do
  begin
    sLine := lstForm[iLoop];
    iPos := Pos('=', sLine);
    iLen := Length(sLine);
    if iPos = 0 then
      continue;

    CmdName := Uppercase(Trim(Copy(sLine, 1, iPos - 1)));
    sWork2 := Trim(Copy(sLine, iPos + 1, iLen));

    if CmdName = 'FORMCAPTION' then
    begin
      with wfrm do
      begin
        Caption := Trim(Copy(sLine, iPos + 1, iLen));
        Name := Trim(sName);
        Height := iFormHeight;
        Width := iFormWidth;
        Tag := 10;
        BorderStyle := bsSizeable;
        BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu];
        Position := poDesktopCenter;
        pnl := TPanel.Create(wfrm);
        with pnl do
        begin
          Parent := wfrm;
          Caption := '';
          Align := alBottom;
          BevelInner := bvNone;
          BevelOuter := bvNone;
          Height := 30;
        end;
        with TButton.Create(wfrm) do
        begin
          Parent := pnl;
          Caption := '&OK';
          Default := True;
          ModalResult := mrOK;
          Left := 235;
          Top := 0;
        end;
        with TButton.Create(wfrm) do
        begin
          Parent := pnl;
          Caption := '&Cancel';
          Cancel := True;
          ModalResult := mrCancel;
          Left := 310;
          Top := 0;
        end;
        pnl := TPanel.Create(wfrm);
        with pnl do
        begin
          Parent := wfrm;
          Caption := '';
          Align := alClient;
          BevelInner := bvRaised;
          BevelOuter := bvNone;
          BorderWidth := 5;
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      lst.Clear;
      StringToList(sWork2, lst, ':');
      if UpperCase(lst[0]) = 'EDITBOX' then
        CreateEditBox
      else if UpperCase(lst[0]) = 'CHECKBOX' then
        CreateCheckBox
      else if UpperCase(lst[0]) = 'COMBOBOX' then
        CreateComboBox
      else if UpperCase(lst[0]) = 'LABEL' then
        CreateLabel;
    end;
  end;

  with wfrm do
  begin
    if hresult1 > 1 then
      hresult2 := 5
    else
      hresult2 := 9;
    Tag := Tag + hresult2;
    Height := Height + hresult2;
  end;

  lst.Free;
end;
```

**And here is the specific code to create the TComboBox, w/ TLabel, for the form:**

```
  procedure CreateComboBox;
  var
    iPos: Integer;
  begin
    with TLabel.Create(wfrm) do
    begin
      Parent := pnl;
      Caption := lst[1];
      Left := 15;
      if hresult1 > 1 then
        hresult2 := 5 * hresult1
      else
        hresult2 := 3 * hresult1;
      Top := wfrm.Tag + hresult2;
      Name := 'lbl' + CmdName;
      Width := 150;
      WordWrap := True;
      AutoSize := True;
      lh := Height;
    end;
    hresult1 := Trunc(lh/13);
    with TComboBox.Create(wfrm) do
    begin
      Parent := pnl;
      Left := 170;
      Width := 200;
      if hresult1 > 1 then
        hresult2 := 5 * hresult1
      else
        hresult2 := 3 * hresult1;
      Top := wfrm.Tag + hresult2;
      Style := csDropDownList;
      Name := UpperCase(CmdName);
      Text := 'Test Text';
      sWork := lst[3];
      lst.Clear;
      StringToList(sWork, lst, ',');
      for iPos := 0 to lst.Count - 1 do
        lst[iPos] := lst[iPos];
      Items.Assign(lst);
//      ItemIndex := 0;
    end;
    wfrm.Tag := wfrm.Tag + ((hresult1 * 13)+ 13);
    wfrm.Height := wfrm.Height + ((hresult1 * 13)+ 13);
    TComboBox(wfrm
  end;
```

NOTE: the above procedure is a child procedure of the CreateForm procedure.

The app uses TStringList lists to store the form definition at script/macro runtime.  Then the above code retrieves that information to create to form when the author wants the form to be shown.  And then creates the form and places the form object into another temporary TStringList list prior to being shown.  This is done so that when the user runs the script/macro and enters the information/settings as requested in the form.  The author may retrieve the requested information/settings from the form before the form is destroyed.

**The form is deleted (if previously created) from tmp TStringList list, created, stored in tmp TStringList list, and shown modally with the following code:**

```
    iPos := lstForms.IndexOf(UpperCase(sWVar2));
    if iPos < 0 then
    begin
      AbortError('Could not find form "' + Trim(sWVar2) + '" defined!');
      Exit;
    end;

    iPos := lstFormsTMP.IndexOf(UpperCase(sWVar2));
    if iPos > -1then
    begin
      TForm(lstFormsTMP.Objects[iPos]).Free;
      lstFormsTMP.Delete(iPos);
      frm.Free;
      iPos := lstFormsTMP.IndexOf(UpperCase(sWVar2));
      if iPos > -1 then
      begin
        AbortError('Form "' + Trim(sWVar2) + '" was not removed from the lstFormsTMP TStringList.');
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    frm := TForm.Create(frmMain);
    CreateForm(frm, sWVar2);
    lstFormsTMP.AddObject(Uppercase(sWVar2), frm);
  end;

  iPos := lstFormsTMP.IndexOf(UpperCase(sWVar2));
  if iPos < 0 then
  begin
    AbortError('Could not find form "' + Trim(sWVar2) + '" defined!');
    Exit;
  end;

  hndHold := SwitchToHandle(frmMain.Handle);
  try
    Result := TForm(lstFormsTMP.Objects[iPos]).ShowModal = mrOK;
  finally
    SwitchToHandle(hndHold);
  end;
```

With the above sets of code the form defined in the running script is created and shown, without to many bugs/errors.  But, even though I have hardcoded the text for the TComboBox.Text property. It is not shown.  Can anyone shed some lite on why this is the case for me?  All other form components, TCheckBox, TEditBox, TLabel, are displayed without any issues, so far.  It is just the TComboBox that is causing me to scratch my head in confusion.

NOTE: Eventually the TComboBox.Text property will be dynamically set based on the authors setting for that property in the form component's definition.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED 8/18/2013, to include the following:

The original code also includes the ability to save/load the form component's settings by way of the TIniFile object. The following code is used to save the setting for the TComboBox:

```
  if frm.Components[i] is TCombobox then
    iniWork.WriteString(frm.Name, TCombobox(frm.Components[i]).Name, TCombobox(frm.Components[i]).Text)
  else
```

and the following to load the TComboBox setting:

```
  if frm.Components[i] is TCombobox then
  begin
    TCombobox(frm.Components[i]).ItemIndex := TCombobox(frm.Components[i]).Items.IndexOf(
      iniWork.ReadString(frm.Name, TCombobox(frm.Components[i]).Name, TCombobox(frm.Components[i]).Text));
  end
```

With the above code it looks to me like the setting is being save from and loaded back into the TComboBox's Text property. Now when the TComboBox setting is loaded, the form is changed after it has been created and placed, as an object, into the tmp TStringList list and prior to being shown modally.  Yet, when the form is shown the **Text** property, as set by the above load code above, is shown.

It is because of the above that I am confused.  Why does it work at this point, after the form is created.  Yet not when the form is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a drop down list because you set the style to `csDropDownList`. That means that the edit control of the combo box can only display items that are contained in its list control.

For a drop down list combo, setting the `Text` property has no effect. Instead of using the `Text` property, you should be specifying `ItemIndex`.

Comment: That is what I had thought, but the original code has a section to allow the author to save/load settings for a form to/from file, using the TIniFile object to access the file. The initial uses the following to get the setting:

Comment: I stand by my answer. Trying to assign to `Text` in a `csDropDownList` combo has no effect. It's trivial to write a simple program to prove that this is the case. If you want to use `csDropDownList` then change the state by assigning to `ItemIndex`. Just as the code that you added in your edit does. Read your own edit very carefully. Look specifically at the code that assigns to `ItemIndex`.